# speedup macOS Sierra startup

Tags: startup, macos

I just installed MacOS Sierra on my macBookPro , I realised startup is slower than in Mavericks, can anyone direct me how can I or what Can I do to speed up boot and after booth startup. My MacBook RAM is 4GB, I hope this is not a problem otherwise.

Comment: Can you tell us your MacBook Pro year/model and if you have a hard drive or solid-state? And how long did it take before compared to now? I would recommend you upgrade the RAM.

Comment: Year 2013, processor 2.5 Ghz Intel core i5

Comment: Ok not such an old model. Do you have an SSD or HHD on it, and how fast did it used to boot compared to now? SSDs should boot like 10-30 seconds, HHDs more like 45-1:45 seconds.

Comment: It's HHD, on Mavericks it took less than 30-40 seconds on Sierra it takes around 1 minute to come into full usable desktop

Comment: I haven't upgraded to Sierra yet but I have a 2011 MBP that came with Lion, 4GB of RAM and an SSD, and shortly upgraded to Mountain Lion. It would boot in about 20 seconds. Then I upgraded to 8GB RAM and upgraded to El Capitan, boot time is about the same even though I skipped two versions, just like you skipped two versions. I have to wait and see how it is when I upgrade to Sierra, but I have seen a video where it does take a few seconds extra to boot.

Comment: Ok so if it's HHD it doesn't sound too unreasonable for a 1 minute boot. Unsure if there's anything specific you need to do to change that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is reliable, but I saw on macxdvd.com (I am not recommending their software) that if boot time is slow on Sierra, to try the following:

> Many users reported that updated macOS Sierra boot-up time increased a lot. How to speed up macOS Sierra? It's quite easy. Head to System Preferences > Startup Disk > primary disk and click "Restart" the Mac computer. If it doesn't fix slow Mac macOS Sierra after upgrading to macOS Sierra, reset PRAM.

[Apple has instructions to reset PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063):

> Shut down your Mac.
>
> Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. 
>   Turn on your Mac.
>
> Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
>
> Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
>
> Release the keys.
>
> After resetting NVRAM, you may need to reconfigure settings for speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, and time zone information.

Please comment if this had any effect.

Comment: Thank you! My 2015 MBP had insanely long boot-times after upgrading to macOS High Sierra. Using "Restart" in the Startup Disk preferences fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MacbookPro 2015 and tried the soft reset as mentioned - but it did not help. I solved the issue by starting my computer using the safe mode as described by Apple support. In short: turn off your computer and restart it. Immediately after hearing the startup sound press and hold the shift key. Release when Apple logo appears. Thus the system will try to fix directory issues and your screen will blink and look funny for few seconds...Then you can restart the computer as usual and hopefully be happy again.

Comment: Will I have reinstall any software if I follow what you said?

Answer (score -1):

Get an SSD! It is the best sub-$500 investment you will make for your computer!